# How to redirect http to https for a reactJs SPA behind AWS Elb?

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, http-redirect

I chose to use express server for deployment as pointed to in [deployment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) section of create-react-app user guide. The express server is set up on an EC2 instance and is fronted by an AWS Elb, where the SSL terminates. How do I setup redirection of http requests to https?

I am open to using Nginx as well, if there is a solution.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');
const app = express();

/**
 * Listener port for the application.
 *
 * @type {number}
 */
const port = 8080;

/**
 * Identifies requests from clients that use http(unsecure) and
 * redirects them to the corresponding https(secure) end point.
 *
 * Identification of protocol is based on the value of non
 * standard http header 'X-Forwarded-Proto', which is set by
 * the proxy(in our case AWS ELB).
 * - when the header is undefined, it is a request sent by
 * the ELB health check.
 * - when the header is 'http' the request needs to be redirected
 * - when the header is 'https' the request is served.
 *
 * @param req the request object
 * @param res the response object
 * @param next the next middleware in chain
 */
const redirectionFilter = function (req, res, next) {
  const theDate = new Date();
  const receivedUrl = `${req.protocol}:\/\/${req.hostname}:${port}${req.url}`;

  if (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') === 'http') {
    const redirectTo = `https:\/\/${req.hostname}${req.url}`;
    console.log(`${theDate} Redirecting ${receivedUrl} --> ${redirectTo}`);
    res.redirect(301, redirectTo);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

/**
 * Apply redirection filter to all requests
 */
app.get('/*', redirectionFilter);

/**
 * Serve the static assets from 'build' directory
 */
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

/**
 * When the static content for a request is not found,
 * serve 'index.html'. This case arises for Single Page
 * Applications.
 */
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


console.log(`Server listening on ${port}...`);
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: thanks man, this is way better than installing another dependency to your react app which'll just end up increasing the bundle size

Answer (score 9):

## Using npm:

`npm install --save react-https-redirect`

Supposing a CommonJS environment, you can simply use the component in this way:

```
import HttpsRedirect from 'react-https-redirect';
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
          <Providers>
            <HttpsRedirect>
              <Children />
            </HttpsRedirect>
           <Providers />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option here is to configure your ELB to listen on 80 and 443 and forward those ports to your EC2 instances. On your EC2 instances you then can run Nginx and have it reverse proxy to your express server running on localhost. You'll need this in your Nginx config -

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

You can also find some good posts regarding this such as those I've linked below.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

https://www.bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx

Comment: Appreciate your response. But, I was able to implement a solution without having to use nginx. I posted the solution below, in which the express server itself handles redirection.