# How to redirect from http to https in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Audits in Chrome are showing me a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE because Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page I requested. Google developers is giving me the suggestion to configure my server (node.js?) to redirect from http to https.

I tried the react module "react-https-redirect", but still not passing the audit. I implemented the module like so:

```
render() {
    return (
            <HttpsRedirect>
              <App />
            </HttpsRedirect>
    );
}
```

What do I have to configure to realise the automatic redirection?

Comment: It's because you need to configure the server. What kind of application is it? In .NET we have IIS manager on the server that handles redirects. It's up to your server really

Comment: It's running on node

Comment: Then configure node to redirect to wherever you want it to, not react because of security issues. Check the answer underneath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515251/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-for-a-reactjs-spa-behind-aws-elb) you should use react-https-redirect but as the author says there is some security issues with this. if you can configure the server or use nginx as gateway that would be better than using this module.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my question because react-https-redirect is not working properly. But how do I configure the server? It's running on node

Comment: there is two approach you can use Nginx or Apache. both can act as gateway and redirect every http to https .