# Adding an http redirect to a secure application in React.js

Tags: reactjs, https

I have built a react.js application running on https.  I would like to arrange it so that if the user goes to the non-secure (http) version of the url it gets redirected to https instead of just a not found error.
Heres the code I have now:

```html
                var https = require("https");
                https.createServer(httpsOptions, expressApp)
                    .listen(middle_port);
                const { createServer } = require("https");

                const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
                createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
                    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
                    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
                 }).listen(gui_port, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Gui listening on " + gui_port);

                 });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect from http to https in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289596/how-to-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is possible to do it via React, I would highly suggest you do this at the server level via Nginx or something and add the redirect rules there. If however you still want to do it via React, check out [react-https-redirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-https-redirect)